# Bandwidth control using traffic control `tc` on Strongswan ipsec connection

Tags: vpn, iptables, bandwidth, ipsec, strongswan

I am in the need to use traffic control `tc` to regulate the bandwidth.
From what I known is that I can manage the bandwidth using the following

```
DEV=eth0
RATE="100kbps"

tc qdisc del dev $DEV root
tc qdisc add dev $DEV root handle 1: htb default 10
tc class add dev $DEV parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate $RATE
```

This already caused an overall rate limitation on interface eth0.

But I wanted to have the ipsec connection of a specific network (E.g. 10.0.3.0/24) to filter. So this network is limited by the given rate.

I tried to add the following filters

```
IP="10.0.3.0/24"
tc filter add dev $DEV parent 1: protocol all prio 7 u32 match u32 0 0 flowid 1:1
tc filter add dev $DEV parent 1:1 u32 match ip src $IP flowid 1:10
```

But unfortunately again all traffic on the interface is limited to the rate.
I also tried marking this IP through `iptables` as described here:
https://lists.strongswan.org/pipermail/users/2015-July/008546.html

Is there any chance to control bandwidth on a ipsec virtual ip address.
**Or how to get the virtual ip addresses in legacy ipsec configs as a route based interface (E.g. vti or ipsec0)** to apply `tc` to its interface